# How to programmatically list users with a certain role?

Tags: 6, users

What is the preferred way of programmatically generating a list of users with a certain role?

(I know [how to do it with a database query](http://drupal.org/node/63422), but surely there's a higher-level method.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Drupal 7, `user_load_multiple($uids = array(), $conditions = array(), $reset = FALSE)` 
will load the user details for the given user IDs.
In Drupal 6, there isn't that function, but you can use `$user = user_load(array('uid' => $node->uid));`.

Comment: Looping that line would mean I'd have to iterate through every user in the database (which doesn't scale well) — I'm looking for an efficient, programmatic way to generate a list of only users with a certain role.

Comment: if you are looking for efficient, nothing beats a well crafted db_query, so I guess I don't understand your hesitation at using one.  after all, that's what any routine, drupal provided or otherwise, has to do anyway.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT u.* FROM users u,role r, users_roles ur WHERE r.name="authenticated user" AND r.rid=ur.rid AND ur.uid=u.uid;
```

try this query.

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned in my question, I know how to do it with a database query, and am wondering if there is a higher-level method.

Answer (score 1):

Umm?  Create a view of type USER, filter on USER ROLE, and have field USER NAME?

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to do this programmatically (entirely from code).  I know I can create a View from code, but that seems unnecessarily roundabout/heavyweight for a simple task like this.

Comment: This is not exactly how to do it programmatically.

Comment: what is this 'higher-level method' he speaks of?  something between writing his own query and using the one views creates?

Comment: @jimajamma: Yes, somewhere between those.  For example, if I wish to fetch an object with user data, I call the function `user_load()` --- I don't have to directly query the database, nor do I have to build and execute a View --- resulting in code that's easier to maintain.

Comment: @jimajamma: How would I get a total count of these users per role?