# How could I select all the authenticated users and just only them?

Tags: 7, users

I've a long running Drupal 7 site. Now my client needs a way to select (and act upon) the users who are not in the role "A" and "B", but just "Authenticated Users".

I know that the latter are not in the `users_roles` table which makes the standard admin/people form and the advanced users module useless (they both skip over the Authenticated Users).

Do you know of any module that could do something like that? Unfortunately it seems there is no way to alter the query in the `user.module` (which joins `users_roles`) so I feel like it's a dead end. Should I need to write a module with a form and duplicate most of the features of the admin/people?

Comment: Check this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17248/how-to-programmatically-list-users-with-a-certain-role

Comment: if you solved your issue, mark your answer as correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Views Bulk Operations (VBO) module it is possible, by creating a view to select all the people not in the desired roles.